# Split plugin array into 2 halfs

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm getting the array of plugins on the server using:

```
Plugin[] pls = Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugins();
```

I need to split the array into 2 halfs. I understand that I can split the array into one half using:

```
Plugin[] hHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, 0, pls.length/2);
```

But how do I get the other half?

Edit: ahh, I understand now. thank you all!

Comment: Plugin[] hHalf2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(pls,  pls.length/2, pls.length);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, pls.length / 2, pls.length)
```

When you call `Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, 0, pls.length/2)`, you're getting all of the values from the first value (index 0), up to the middle (index `pls.length / 2`) of the array.

When calling `Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, pls.length / 2, pls.length)`, you're getting all of the values from the middle (index `pls.length / 2`) of the array to the end, effectively getting both halfs of the array.

For example, if you wanted to split it into thirds, you could use:

```
first = Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, 0, pls.length / 3);
second = Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, pls.length / 3, (pls.length / 3) * 2);
third = Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, pls.length / 3, pls.length);
```

If the length is an odd number (for example, in the array `["apples", "oranges", "carrots"]`, you could use:

```
firstHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, 0, Math.round(pls.length / 2));
secondHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, Math.round(pls.length / 2), pls.length);
```

So, your code could look like this:

```
Plugin[] pls = Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugins();

Plugin[] firstHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, 0, Math.round(pls.length / 2));
Plugin[] secondHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, Math.round(pls.length / 2), pls.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

will it not be of form `Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, pls.length/2, pls.length)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 1st half through this

```
Plugin[] hHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(pls, 0, pls.length/2);
```

So you can also get  second half  like this

```
Plugin[] hHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(pls,pls.length/2,pls.length);
```